# Laravel Sub Category and Parent Categories, values not showing

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a subcategory and category list view in my blade file. I have created everything necessary, and yet for some reason, no values are showing up in my view. There are no errors showing up, but I am not seeing any values either.

This is my view

```
 @foreach ($pro_cat as $cat)
              <ul class="list-group">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" class="card-header list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <option value="{{ $cat->id }}">{{ ucwords($cat->name) }}</option>
                      <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ count($pro_cat)}}</span>
                    </a>
                    @foreach ($sub_cat as $cat)
                        @if($sub_cat->cat_id == $pro_cat->id)
                    <div id="collapseExample" class="collapse">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                            <option class="list-group-item" value="{{ $cat->id }}">{{ ucwords($cat->name) }}</option>
                            </ul>
                            @endif
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach
```

I'm not sure if its related to the view, or if its a mistake in my controller, but I've attached my controller below just in case. Any help would seriously be appreciated

```
 $pro_cat = Pro_cat::where('id', NULL)->get();
  $sub_cat = Sub_cat::where('cat_id','!=',NULL)->get();
    return view('liturgy.posts.index')->with('pro_cat', $pro_cat)->with('posts', $posts)->with('sub_cat', $sub_cat);
```

Comment: `Pro_cat::where('id', NULL)`. So your `Pro_cat` has some `id` which is `NULL`? Is `id` not the primary key in your table? If yes, how can any row have `NULL` value?

Comment: i tried getting rid of that as well, and just have it as where('id'), but i still didn't get any values

Comment: You really need to understand Laravel Eloquent and basics of SQL. If you just put a `where('id')` without any value for it to search, how would it know which value to retrieve. Probably you need this `Pro_cat::all();`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that's easy. Create your relationship like this

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model {

    public function sub_category()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'cat_id');
    }

    public function parent_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'cat_id');
    }

}
```

Then, when call the model, add with(), like so

```
$categories = Category::with('sub_category')->get();

return view('someview', compact('categories'));
```

Or just add `$with` property on your model, like protected $with = ['sub_category', 'parent_category'];. This will automatically add the relationship to the collection.

The views

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {!! $category->name !!}
    @foreach($category->sub_category as $sub_category)
        {!! $sub_category->name !!}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: You mixed ap belongsTo and hasMany in relations. hasMany must be in sub_category(), belongTo must be in parent_category(). Foreign key must be cat_id (in authors situation). And in both relations params must be (self::class, 'cat_id')

Answer (score 0):

Add relations to your Category model:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'cat_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'cat_id');
}
```

Get categories with eager loading children relation in controller:

```
$posts = blahblah...
$categories = Category::with('children')->get();
return return view('liturgy.posts.index', compact('categories', 'posts'));
```

Access relation like simple attribute in view:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <ul class="list-group">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" class="card-header list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ ucwords($category->name) }}</option>
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ $categories->count() }}</span>
        </a>
        @foreach ($category->children as $child)
            <div id="collapseExample" class="collapse">
                 <ul class="list-group">
                     <option class="list-group-item" value="{{ $child->id }}">{{ ucwords($child->name) }}
                     </option>
                 </ul>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```